# Не могу разобраться с Http ответом

Tags: http, wireshark

Не могу понять что именно возвращается в ответ. Это что-то зашифрованное/закодированное??

```
A
..........
1AA
..A..0...J..=e.{0.....i/{h...8.....ag..*...(m.c..8.o..<....|.p.I..s.MN....x.D.\dp(.E.B,^=MI...:....]m.].u.zk..^#..x....H3   P0.8RD8N..~.0...z.,.e.....v;...\.HE..X...m.".C.T.....H.@..7.;.]`G..>..;.L.z...........AU.$A... ...u...$.....Z...-Uyh3.D:@..XK.....#.y..........~...g7....g.9;.K_..&j...uV....7......%<..RU."....61X.p.Y..\.L_\./..v..N.l.w.....'...g._..@.[.O.*.+.m.!....6Y.a..7........=..p......n.s.eD....f......Oq..'...*....
0
```

Помогите разобраться ;(

[image: Кусок из wireshark]

Имеются другие примеры ответов, если необходимо...

Comment: gzip же. об этом хидер и говорит. Content-Encoding: gzip, то есть просто сжали трафик и его нужно распаковать

Comment: Возможно я чтото недопонимаю, но я делал так: file -> export object -> http, потом выбрал нужное и сохранил. гдето вычитал, что сохраняется уже распакованный ответ, но в нем те же самые строки.. что я делаю не так? как их правильно распаковать?

Comment: Это в какой программе экспорт? В блокноте что ле?

Comment: Это все из wireshark'а

Comment: Может под распакованным подразумевается избавление от упаковки в протокольные пакеты. Ведь с с этой точки зрения в них запакован gzip. Из пакета http его извлекли (распаковали)  А дальше уж сами как-нибудь. Иногда слова имеют разный смысл в зависимости от контекста

Comment: Благодарю за ответы, буду разбираться.